# ToolStripMenuItem and KeyPress or KeyDown event

Tags: c#, keypress

I am using `ToolStripDropDownButton` and dynamically adding menu items as below:

```
toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Clear();

ToolStripMenuItem item1 = new ToolStripMenuItem("Item1");
toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Add(item1);

ToolStripMenuItem item2 = new ToolStripMenuItem("Item2");
toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Add(item2);
```

I would like to delete the selected menu item when the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key is pressed. But the `ToolStripMenuItem` doesn't have `KeyPress` or `KeyDown` event.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0. Any suggestions on how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: What do you mean by "*selected menu item*"? Is it the **hovered** menu item?

Comment: Yes, hovered menu item. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DropDown` element of your menu, then bind `KeyDown` event to it.
Now you know which key is pressed on the menu, but you don't know which menu item is pointed with mouse cursor. Bind `MouseEnter` event of `ToolStripMenuItem`s and you can now store which one is pointed. Now you know which item is pointed and which key is pressed when `DropDown`'s `KeyDown` event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you want to delete the selected item from a dropdown list when you click on separate delete button. Is that what you're trying to do? If so then you need to be looking at the click event of the delete button and deleting the list item based upon the current selected item. KeyPress of KeyDown aren't needed.

Comment: I don't have any Delete button, only drop down menu items.

I would like to delete the selected item when Delete key pressed. The issue is ToolStripMenuItem don't have KeyPress or KeyDown event. 

Any suggestions or workaround approach?

Comment: Oh I see. Then, no you can't do that. The ToolStrip eats up all the keyboard events. The only way to do what you want would be to create a new ToolStrip control derived from the original one and add in the bits you want. I would rethink what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I may need to use a different approach if it can not be done easily.

Answer (score 0):

The enclosing ToolStrip gets the key events so you can handle it there with something like:

```
toolStripDropDownButton1.KeyDown += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        foreach (var item in ((ToolStrip)s).Items.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>())
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                ((ToolStrip)s).Items.Remove(item);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

(this code is completely untested)

I used the *((ToolStrip)s)* inside the event handler in case you wanted to define a static method elsewhere that could be called by multiple different ToolStrip instances. You could, of course, in this case replace *((ToolStrip)s)* with *toolStripDropDownButton1*.